# Why is my (fluid sim) geometry different after rendering (2.78a + cycles)?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, fluid-simulation, geometry

I have a fluid sim I am using to create a splash over 10 frames. The desired look is on the 2nd frame, as pictured below. So why if it shows up in both previews, is the geometry (not to mention the camera perspective) rendering so radically different? Note the droplets in the geometry do not appear in the rendering, for example. I saw in another question that keyframing might have something to do with it, but auto keyframes are off, and it was just the fluid simulation that took care of it all. And yes, there is only one camera, and in case it is relevant I am using cycles and nodes.[image: top left is the render]

Comment: Fluid domain has 2 different resolutions: "final" and "preview"

Comment: @lemon Do I have to rebake after modifying just the preview domain? Also, it seems the maximum resolution for preview is 100, my final is currently set to 150 and my preview was 50 when I did the above.

Comment: I think the bake is done for the final rendering, but I'm not sure of that: give it a try as I can not confirm the behavior.

Comment: A quick test (without rebaking) just switching the "Render display" (in physics tab for fluid domain) to "Preview" instead of "Final" renders my desired geometry. Very strange behavior, since the "Preview" is a lower resolution than "Final", where it looks like the opposite is going on.

Comment: Preview and Final are both being baked in one shot. The number you enter is a number of subdivisions on the domain. Preview exists to work with a lighter mesh in the viewport. Notice that in your images, the final render has finer detail. That means, the final render mesh also contains more polygons. Unfortunately, when simulating, this also leads to changed behavior in the fluid. If you really want to see exactly what you get, make the resolution settings for preview and final identical and bake.